# Recursive function in haskell to capitilize each word by in a list of strings

Tags: function, haskell, recursion

I need to writea function titleRec :: [String] -> [String] which, given a list of
words, capitalises them as a title should be capitalised. The proper
capitalisation of a title (for our purposes) is as follows: The first word
should be capitalised. Any other word should be capitalised if it is
at least four letters long.

I came as far as,

```
capitalisedRec :: String -> String
capitalisedRec [] = []
capitalisedRec (x:xs) = toUpper x : lowered xs 
                       where 
                        lowered [] = []
                        lowered (x:xs) = toLower x : lowered xs

capitilized2 :: String -> String
capitilized2 xs = [toLower x | x <-xs]

titleRec :: [String] -> [String]
titleRec [] = []
titleRec (x:xs) = capitalisedRec x : adjust xs
                 where
                    adjust [] = []
                    adjust (y:ys) = [if (length y >= 4) then capitalisedRec y else capitilized2 y | y<- ys]
```

But when I run it on a list of strings, for example titleRec ["tHe", "bOSun", "ANd", "thE", "BriDGe"] it results in ["The","and","the","Bridge"], basically skips over the second word. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code reads:

```
adjust (y:ys) = 
  [ if (length y >= 4) 
    then capitalisedRec y
    else capitilized2 y 
  | y <- ys]
```

but the first `y` is not used later on, discarding it! The latter `y` is unrelated, and shadows the first one.

A minimal modification fix would be:

```
adjust (y:ys) = 
  [ if (length y2 >= 4)
    then capitalisedRec y2
    else capitilized2 y2 
  | y2 <- y:ys]
```

I would strongly recommend that you always keep warnings enabled using `-Wall`. Doing so, GHC would warn about `y` being unused (and about the shadowing as well).

Comment: Thank you, It's my first time trying to learn a functional language so I'm having a hard time. I use vscode to compile, where can I write the -Wall command? The terminal gives error saying: <interactive>:35:1: error:
    • Data constructor not in scope: Wall
    • Perhaps you meant variable ‘all’ (imported from Prelude)

Comment: @EgeGülce You can use it in one of these places: 1) when you start ghci e.g. `ghci -Wall Myfile.hs` (the same for `ghc`), 2) after you start ghci using `:set -Wall` at the prompt, 3) in the first (or so) line of the .hs file, using `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}`